# Why are "static final" fields allowed in inner classes?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I have a doubt in using Inner Classes in java. Here is my code.

Code:

```
public class Test{

      public class InnerClass{
             public static int num = 10;
      }       

}
```

It's  not allowed. I got the error message "The field num cannot be declared static; static fields can only be declared in static or top level types".

```
public class Test{

      public class InnerClass{
             public static final int num = 10;
      }       

}
```

But It's allowed. I have not declared `InnerClass` as static and top level element but how it works?

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you the answer? If the class is static or if it is top level, it is allowed.

Comment: @KarthikT - That's not the same question.

Comment: This question is taking it a step further to ask why a constant (`static final`) field is allowed.

Comment: @KarthikT , Please read my question. I am asking why constant fields are allowed in inner class?

Comment: @PaulBellora Oh, the difference an applicable title makes.

Comment: @bharathi Sorry my miss-understanding, will vote to reopen if it gets closed..

Comment: Actually this question is also semi-addressed in the other answer: only "compile-time constant fields" are allowed to be `static final` in this context. (Of course, one could ask _why_ that was decided. I guess convenience?)

Answer (score 8):

To quote from the linked answer.

> [8.1.2 Inner Classes and Enclosing Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#262890)
>   ...
>   Inner classes may not declare static members, **unless they are compile-time constant fields** (§15.28).

`final` makes them constant once initialized, `= 10` is a compile time constant value. Thus it is allowed.